# PHP cURL: retrieve search data from yahoo/ google api?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I tried to test php_curl on yahoo curl service but I get an error back from yahoo.

```
// create a new cURL resource
$handle = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
// http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=persimmon&results=10
curl_setopt_array(
    $handle,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'appid=YahooDemo&query=test&results=10',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    ) 
);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach($xml->Result as $x) {
    echo $x->Title.'<br/>';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
```

result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Message] => The service has been shut down. For further details, please see the Deprecated Services blog post http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes
)
```

any examples to retrieve **search data** from yahoo **since that service is deprecated**? It seems require some payments from their [BOSS API](http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/#overview).

what about googel api - where can I go for if I want to get search data returned from google?

Answer (score 6):

> any idea why?

Did you **read the message?!**

> The service has been shut down. For further details, please see the Deprecated Services blog post  http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/08/api_updates_and_changes

That URL says:

> Other non-BOSS search APIs such as Web Search, Image Search, News Search, Related Suggestion, and Site Explorer APIs will shut down with no further support in YQL.

So...

> so, how can I get authenticated to retrieve data/ statuses from twitter?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth